# Flutter Native Crash

Tags: android, flutter, crash, flutter-layout

My application started having the following error:

```
signal 11 (SIGSEGV), code 1 (SEGV_MAPERR)

em libflutter.so (offset 0x260000)
```

I'm using Flutter version 1.9.1. Could anyone tell me why this error occurs? Are they outdated plugins or my business rules? Until a few days ago I didn't have this Crash problem
[image]